# Is it possible to proceed direct geo-referencing and ortho-rectification for a GeoTIFF with GDAL/OpenCV in one step

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, orthorectification, c, opencv

I work under Debian Linux and want to ortho-rectify and geo-reference images aquired by a tilted twin camera system using:

- the attitude parameter (roll, ptich and heading) of the gyro-stabilized platform and
- the position data (longitude, latitude, altitude)

from a parallel running IMU/GNSS logged at the mide-exposure time mark (see image below).

[image]

The flight platform is working over a sea surface, so terrain issues could be neglected.
The transformation from longitude, latitude, altitude (ellipsiodal) to x, y, z (ortho-height GEOID) is done by the proj tool.

Normally I start to correct the perspective distortion ("ortho rectification") using openCV using

- `getPerspective` to implement the passpoint configuration and get the rotation matrix setup and
- `warpPerspective` to create the new image with a given resampling algorithm

and apply the geo-referencing aftermath

- `gdal_translate` to write the ..gpc's and the SRS and
- `gdalwarp` to create the GeoTIFF container with the expected resolution (resampling routine/ type again).

So the GDAL is here used as "GeoTiff-Driver" to implement the SRS metadata and to assure the resolution via passpoints which are calculated also in the `getPerscpective` process before.

To avoid two interpolation steps, based on the two tools and saving time and resources,
I want do do this in one programatical step (tool) after reading the raw TIFF image into the RAM.

**Question:** Is either

- the creation of a GeoTIFF (augmentation with the co-ordiante system metadata) using openCV or
- on the other hand the perspective correction in GDAL (including the C-API)

in that way possible?

Comment: I'm not that experienced in orthorectification, but if my general understanding of your Q is approximately correct the least-time/resources method would be to apply all perspective and warp calculations to [tag:vrt] first and then gdalwarp/translate at the from .vrt to geotiff.

Comment: I am doing the same thing now and fine tuning with with QGIS.  It seems to work well